# How to Inject 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' using AddTransient Method in XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, .net-core, xunit

I am trying to Unit test a  method which in in class `TWService` and require two dependencies to Inject i.e `IXMLResponseSave` and `IConfiguration`. I am able to inject dependency for `IXMLResponseSave` using below line in my Fact.

```
services.AddTransient<IXMLResponseSave, XMLFileResponseSaveBlob>();
```

How should I inject dependency for  `IConfiguration`.

Below is my sample Controller code which i want to test.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ApiController]
public class TWBookingController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ITWService _twservice;

    public TWBookingController(ITWService tWService)
    {
        _twservice = tWService;
    }      

    public IActionResult SomeTestAction([FromBody]SomeParameter someParameter)
    {

        if(someParameter !=null && ValidatePassenger(someParameter) && (someParameter.pnrRequired>0 || someParameter.quotesrRequired > 0))
        {
            var result = _twservice.SomeTestMethod(someParameter);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        else
            return BadRequest();
    }      
}
```

---

```
public class TWService : ITWService
{
    private IConfiguration _config;   
    private IXMLResponseSave _xMLResponseSave;
    private string format = "Mddyyyyhhmmss";

    public TWService(IConfiguration config, IXMLResponseSave xMLResponseSave)
    {
        _config = config;
        _xMLResponseSave = xMLResponseSave;
    }

    public TWAutoSearchRes SomeTestMethod(SomeParameter someParameter)
    {
        //Some Implementation

    }
}
```

Code written for Unit Test.

```
[Fact]
public void Test_Valid()
{
    someParameter_Valid = BuildValidRequest();
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddTransient<ITWService, TWService>();           
    services.AddTransient<IXMLResponseSave, XMLFileResponseSaveBlob>();            
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    _tWService = serviceProvider.GetService<ITWService>();
    var response = _tWService.SomeTestMethod(someParameter_Valid);
    Assert.IsType<OkResult>(response);
}
```

Currently I am getting below error message:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate ''

Comment: While it should just be a matter of injecting a mock of the desired interface, the fact that you are injecting `IConfiguration` indicates a deeper design issue. Leading me to think that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why does `TWService` need `IConfiguration` and what is its real purpose?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the code snippet that will help you to resolve `IConfiguration` dependency

```
services.AddTransient<IConfiguration>(sp =>
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            return configurationBuilder.Build();
        });
```

You have to include following NuGet packages to run the above code inside the *Test project:

1. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

p.s. You don't need to inject real objects to write unit test cases rather you could use Mock Objects. In addition, Instead of passing `IConfiguration` interface, you can pass a POCO class or IOptions interface.

Comment: Awesome, I had already done the build previously in the code I just needed to add the angle brackets type IConfiguration to make it work! Guess it needed a cast from ConfigurationRoot type :

.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration)