# How to add AWS SystemsManager to Startup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing AWS Lambda NET6 app, it was created in VS2022 using AWS Template.
The app has Startup only.
Where can I add this code?

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddSystemsManager("/myapplication");
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Or may be it can be done other way?

Comment: It should be inside the `LocalEntryPoint.cs` class. Don't you have that class in your template?

Comment: I have it. If I add the code to this class it will be for local run only but not for run in AWS?

Comment: Posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AWS serverless template, the app configuration should be registered in the `Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)` method in the `LambdaEntryPoint.cs` file

```
public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
       protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
       {
           builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                   {
                       builder.AddSystemsManager("/myapplication/");
                   })
                  .UseStartup<Startup>();
       }
       ...
}
```

Then, in the `Startup.cs` class, you can bind the SSM configuration values to the respective `TOptions` class:

```
public class Startup
{
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
       }
       ...
}
```

Finally, you can inject the `TOptions` anywhere inside your project and access the configuration values:

```
public sealed class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
        private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseSettings;
    
        public ApplicationDbContext(
             DbContextOptions options,
             IOptions<DatabaseSettings> databaseSettings) : base(options)
        {
             _databaseSettings = databaseSettings.Value;
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: In the 1st your comment the mistake, it should be added to LambdaEntryPoint only, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. It was a mistake.

Comment: Yet another question: the Startup is the same for local and AWS run. How to read from AWS Systems Manager or from appsettings.config in case of local run?  Or it will be the same code:  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings"));
       } ?

Comment: In LocalEntryPoint, instead of AddSystemsManager method, you can use AddJsonFile method and it will let you process the config from appsettlings file. Refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628322/how-to-inject-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration-using-addtrans/56630416#56630416

Comment: However, if you have access to your AWS environment from your local machine, then you can use AddSystemsManager method in the LocalEntryPoint